# When both list options get selected, then blink the calculate button with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

When both options get selected, I want the calculate button to blink. I am trying, but it is not working. How should I use blink button when an option is selected?

```
   <form>
      <select class="form-contol">
          <option value='0'> Select</option>
          <option value='1'> 1</option>
          <option value='2'> 2</option>
          <option value='3'> 3</option>
     </select>

    <select class="form-contol">
         <option value='0'> Select</option>
         <option value='1'> 1</option>
         <option value='2'> 2</option>
         <option value='3'> 3</option>
  </select>
   <button type="button" class="calculate-btn">Claculate</button>
   <button type="reset" class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
</form>
```

style.css

```
.form-contol{
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
   color: #555555;
   display: block;
   font-size: 14px;
   height: 34px;
   line-height: 1.42857;
   padding: 6px 12px;
   transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 50%;
   margin-bottom:10px;
 }
  button{
     background-color:transparent;
    background-color: #5CB85C;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #4CAE4C;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-right:10px;
   }
```

jquery.js

```
  $(".form-contol").change(function(){
   $(".calculate-btn").animate();
  });
 $(".reset-btn").click(function(){
       $(".calculate-btn").removeAttr("style");
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/3jLAZ/

After the reset button is clicked, stop the animation and blink next. Give me an example.

Comment: Like this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jLAZ/1/)**

Comment: yes my friends, how use... explain

Comment: Just copy that script in your code.

Comment: where you post and how use vote up

Comment: Added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3jLAZ/16/)**

```
$(".form-contol").change(function(){

    blink();
});
function blink() {
    $(".calculate-btn").animate({
        opacity: '0'
    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: '1'
        }, blink);
    });
}
```

To manipulate the time for **[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**, add time(millisec) parameter as below.

```
$(".calculate-btn").animate({
    opacity: '0'
},200, function(){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: '1'
    },200, blink);
});
```

Comment: hello my friends. i want two list is the same select it is blink. how use..... please

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(".form-contol").change(function(){
    $(".calculate-btn").fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3jLAZ/6/)

And If you want continues blinking then use

```
$(".form-contol").change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
    $(".calculate-btn").fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    },200);
});
```

Demo for continuous blinking - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3jLAZ/8/)

Comment: You can make fade slow by putting time in miliseconds like i have put 100 in each and total of it i.e. 200 in timeInterval.

Comment: Do you mean when both list option get selected ( means value other than select) then blink button, right?

Comment: yes i konw. but two select is two select. button is blink. but your answer is one select option is select and button is blink. how use the same choose tow list is selected... please

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/3jLAZ/22/  start blinking when select two list and then stop if you select 'select' option from one of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :

```
$(".form-contol").change(function(){
    document.getElementById("calculate-btn").style.backgroundColor="red";
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('calculate-btn').style.backgroundColor=''", 500);


});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3jLAZ/10/